# invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1044.0'

Tags: python, object-detection

I'm trying to run the following code in the terminal to create train.record

```
!python convert_to_tfrecord.py -x xml -l label_map.pbtxt -o train.record -i images
```

Where xml is the folder of the xml files and images is the folder of the original images. It gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convert_to_tfrecord.py", line 165, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 303, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "convert_to_tfrecord.py", line 152, in main
    examples = xml_to_csv(args.xml_dir)
  File "convert_to_tfrecord.py", line 82, in xml_to_csv
    int(root.find('size')[0].text),
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1044.0'
```

The relevant code for convert_to_tfrecord.py is:

```
def xml_to_csv(path):
    """Iterates through all .xml files (generated by labelImg) in a given directory and combines
    them in a single Pandas dataframe.
    Parameters:
    ----------
    path : str
        The path containing the .xml files
    Returns
    -------
    Pandas DataFrame
        The produced dataframe
    """

    xml_list = []
    for xml_file in glob.glob(path + '/*.xml'):
        tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
        root = tree.getroot()
        for member in root.findall('object'):
            value = (root.find('filename').text,
                     int(root.find('size')[0].text),
                     int(root.find('size')[1].text),
                     member[0].text,
                     int(member[4][0].text),
                     int(member[4][1].text),
                     int(member[4][2].text),
                     int(member[4][3].text)
                     )
            xml_list.append(value)
    column_name = ['filename', 'width', 'height',
                   'class', 'xmin', 'ymin', 'xmax', 'ymax']
    xml_df = pd.DataFrame(xml_list, columns=column_name)
    return xml_df
```

It seems like it's an error with the width, but I don't know how I should fix it. Appreciate any help!

EDIT: I just tried int(float(...)), but it still doesn't fix the error

Comment: i think it doesn't like the ".0" part at the end of the text

Comment: This sounds like you might want to convert to a float instead, or first to a float and from there to an int.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I just tried, but it doesn't fix the error, I don't quite get why it can't be converted to int

Comment: "EDIT: I just tried int(float(...)), but it still doesn't fix the error"--- Please give the errors you get after trying `int(float())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your number is a decimal string**

So at first, you need to convert to float and then to int as it has a decimal.

```
def xml_to_csv(path):
    """Iterates through all .xml files (generated by labelImg) in a given directory and combines
    them in a single Pandas dataframe.
    Parameters:
    ----------
    path : str
        The path containing the .xml files
    Returns
    -------
    Pandas DataFrame
        The produced dataframe
    """

    xml_list = []
    for xml_file in glob.glob(path + '/*.xml'):
        tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
        root = tree.getroot()
        for member in root.findall('object'):
            value = (root.find('filename').text,
                     int(float(root.find('size')[0].text)),
                     int(float(root.find('size')[1].text)),
                     member[0].text,
                     int(float(member[4][0].text)),
                     int(float(member[4][1].text)),
                     int(float(member[4][2].text)),
                     int(float(member[4][3].text))
                     )
            xml_list.append(value)
    column_name = ['filename', 'width', 'height',
                   'class', 'xmin', 'ymin', 'xmax', 'ymax']
    xml_df = pd.DataFrame(xml_list, columns=column_name)
    return xml_df
```

**For example:**

```
>>> int('1044.0')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    int('1044.0')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1044.0'
>>> int(float('1044.0'))
1044
```